# Does the LinkedIn API v2 comply with the OAuth 2.0 spec?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

As far as I can tell, OAuth 2.0 expects user information requests to be retrieved from a single endpoint, but the LinkedIn v2 API separates email into a separate endpoint from other basic user information (id, name and profile image).

Our product's generic OAuth 2 implementation only handles a single user info endpoint, so I'm trying to determine whether our implementation is incomplete, or if it's a problem with the implementation on the LinkedIn side (or the third option, there is a way to do it that I have not found).

Breaking the problem into 2 logical questions:

1) Does separating that information into 2 endpoints comply with OAuth 2.0?

2) Have I missed something, and is there a way to fetch email along with other basic user information (which was previously combined in the v1 basic user info endpoint)?

I have looked through all of the v2 API documentation, in particular the migration docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context) and related information about the endpoint changes, as well as various OAuth 2 documentation / open ID specifications.

Comment: As you mentioned, email and profile data are now separate APIs.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherOu, it certainly does look like there's no way around making a second, separate call.